# Better put code in same class or in different class?

Tags: java

I'm newbie programming in `java`.
I'm doing some `forms` and in one of them I put some *fields, a button and a JTextArea*. The idea is when I click in `button` makes a connection to `external database` and in `JTextArea` shows me the connection return (if is okay or if is failed and the error).

So I've created a `class` with the `UI` and a class(connection name) with the *attributes database, port, username, password* ... that make connection to external database.

I don't know if these organization mode is the best way to make it. I should include class connection in the same class of the `UI`,? How should I pass values of the form to the class connection, by a method?

Could you suggest me how to make it?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but roughly speaking ... most developers will agree that you would need to structure you code in _layers_, one which contains the UI classes, another one which contains the business logic classes, and another one which contains classes in charge of the data access logic.

Answer (score 1):

As lealceldeiro commented, this is opinion based, but there are some structures that it is good for these types of applications. What I've been taught and have been using is MVC(Model, View, Controller) structure.

- The model is responsible for managing the data of the application. It receives user input from the controller.
- The view means presentation of the model in a particular format.
- The controller responds to the user input and performs interactions on the data model objects. The controller receives the input, optionally validates it and then passes the input to the model.

I usually make packages/modules called controllers, views and models. So I think you're on the right track here.

Let's say you have one class for your GUI, where the button onClickListener is. That would be your View.
Your models would be the class that you use to connect to the database, and maybe some classes/models in which you store the data from your database queries.
For you I would suggest to make another class that will be your controller. This class would contain your database object, and you can use this to make queries to the database and update your models. One of these could be connectToDatabase(), and you could call this method from your GUI when the button is clicked.

I hope I explained this well enough, and good luck!